# Making a get request with a url that has special characters

Tags: php, get, query-string

I am trying to make this request

```
fopen("http://192.168.0.116:9090/sendsms?phone=4456666&text=url#&password=","r");
```

to send an sms from my android device but i can't seem to send the message successfully and i suspect that `#` is complicating things.

The `#` in url must remain there as part of the message itself.

`phone` is the telephone number and `text` is the text message.

How can i make the get request work?.

Comment: try `text=".urlencode(url)."#&password` so your sms text will be properly escaped inside the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `#` character indicates a *fragment* in URLs, so the part after that is actually ignored right now. You need to escape it properly, for example like this:

```
$myUrl = 'http://192.168.0.116:9090/sendsms?'.http_build_query([
    'phone' => '4456666',
    'text' => 'url#',
    'password' => '',
]);
```

[Docs here on `http_build_query'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

You can also properly escape the individual values with [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Answer (score 1):

This shall work

```
fopen("http://192.168.0.116:9090/sendsms?phone=4456666&text=url%23&password=","r");
```

as `#` is `%23`

Comment: While this solves the problem for the specific URL in the question, it's not a fundamental solution to the issue he is having. I highly doubt the text is hardcoded to always be the same.

Comment: Leave it to the wizards to know `#` is `%23`. Thanks. :)